# Two table mapping in single map class

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a table structure something like this

```
table Collection
  Id
  Name

table Product
  Id
  Name

table Item
  Id
  Collection_Id
  Product_Id
```

What i would like is to map the Collection above to one single class named:

```
Class Collection
  Id
  Name
  List<Product> Products
```

and I have Product class is :

```
Class Product
  Id
  Name
```

How do I do that with fluent nhibernate ? Anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a many to many mapping.

You will need to have a List<> on both classes of the other object and the following mappings in your fluent file

```
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)
        .Table("tblCollection_Product")
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.All();

    HasManyToMany(x => x.Collections)
        .Table("tblCollection_Product")
        .Cascade.All();
```

There is a good article about what you are trying to do [here](http://massimilianopeluso.com/2011/03/28/many-to-many-mapping-using-fluent-nhibernate/)